# How can I make this code more polymorphic?

Tags: haskell

I'm working with the following code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Lib where

import           Protolude hiding (from, try)

import           Control.Exception.Safe
import           Database.Esqueleto
import           Database.Persist.TH

newtype PingId =
  PingId Int
  deriving (Enum, Eq, Integral, Num, Ord, Real, Show)

data Ping = Ping
  {
  } deriving (Show)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings] [persistLowerCase|
DbPing sql=pings
|]

pingToDbPing :: Ping -> DbPing
pingToDbPing _ = undefined

class (PersistEntity b, ToBackendKey SqlBackend b) =>
      ToPersistEntity a b | a -> b where
  toPersistEntity :: a -> b

type family FromKey a :: * where
  FromKey DbPingId = PingId

instance ToPersistEntity Ping DbPing where
  toPersistEntity = pingToDbPing

data DbConfig = DbConfig
  { dbConnectionPool :: ConnectionPool
  }

runDB
  :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader DbConfig m)
  => SqlPersistT IO b -> m b
runDB q = do
  pool <- asks dbConnectionPool
  liftIO $ runSqlPool q pool

saveDB
  :: ( Exception e
     , ToPersistEntity value record
     , Num (FromKey (Key record))
     , MonadCatch m
     , MonadIO m
     , MonadReader DbConfig m
     , FromKey (Key record) ~ key
     )
  => value -> m (Either e key)
saveDB x =
  fmap (fromIntegral . fromSqlKey) <$>
  try (liftIO . evaluate =<< runDB (insert (toPersistEntity x)))
```

In short I have domain objects (e.g `Ping`), `ToPersistEntity` type class to convert those into their database representation, `FromKey` type family to map between database / domain object id's, and `saveDB` function that works for anything satisfying those criteria.

As the next step I wish to create a type class to abstract persisting the objects so that my other functions can be polymorphic in `MonadStore` and I can have different instances for use in my application and for testing. For use in my app I would like to reuse the generic `saveDB` function. Ideally I would like to have something along the lines of:

```hs
class (Monad m) =>
      MonadStore m where
  save
    :: (Exception e)
    => value -> m (Either e key)
```

with `save` type class method delegating to `saveDB` when used in my application. That works fine if I make type class methods specialised to specific types such as `Ping` and `PingId`.

```hs
class (Monad m) =>
      MonadStore m where
  savePing
    :: (Exception e)
    => Ping -> m (Either e PingId)

instance (MonadCatch m, MonadIO m, Monad m, MonadReader DbConfig m) =>
         MonadStore m where
  savePing = saveDB
```

but has the drawback of having to define a new method for each of my objects.

Trying to define my desired instance:

```hs
instance (MonadCatch m, MonadIO m, Monad m, MonadReader DbConfig m) =>
         MonadStore m where
  save = saveDB
```

produces a type error:

```
/home/ppb/Code/haskell/test/src/Lib.hs:86:10: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘key’ with ‘FromKey (Key record0)’
        arising from a use of ‘saveDB’
      ‘key’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          save :: forall e value key.
                  Exception e =>
                  value -> m (Either e key)
        at src/Lib.hs:86:3
    • In the expression: saveDB
      In an equation for ‘save’: save = saveDB
      In the instance declaration for ‘MonadStore m’
    • Relevant bindings include
        save :: value -> m (Either e key) (bound at src/Lib.hs:86:3)
```

and no matter what I try I can't figure out how to make a valid instance where `save` delegates to `saveDB`. Is there any way I could make this work? I'm also interested to better understand the error the compiler produces.

Comment: A class with only one instance is just a complicated way to write a function. `instance ... => MonadStore m` says "every type constructor `m` is a `MonadStore` instance in the following way" (and only later are constraints resolved).  Such instances are almost never what you want -- instances should be like `instance ... => MonadStore (Something ...)`, where `Something` is a concrete type/constructor.